# SLURM: same script run on different but sequentially numbered files

Tags: slurm

The cluster I use just switched to SLURM and I'm trying to do something I think is very simple. I have a script I want to run on many files numbered sequentially, like:

```
python script.py file1.gz
python script.py file2.gz
python script.py file3.gz
```

I have some pieces, but can't figure out how to put them together to run. I think I need to use `#SBATCH --array=0-29` to call the number of files, and `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` is also involved.

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=4G
#SBATCH --array=0-29   ##my files go from file1 - file30

$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
```

I'm not sure how to incorporate `SBATCH --array` and `ARRAY_TASK_ID` to get `script.py` running on all files at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=4G
#SBATCH --array=1-30   ##my files go from file1 - file30

python script.py "file${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}.gz"
```

You better number the array elements like the file numbering you have. And then, call the script with the proper file name created with that SLURM variable.

This jobs submission script queues an array of jobs, each job having a time limit of 24h, uses up to 4GiB of memory and only runs one task (of one processor).